# Windows 10 reinstall: what difference between formatting before reinstall and selecting the "delete all files" native option?

Tags: windows, windows-10

When reinstalling Windows, I've always booted on the DVD and in install options: selected fresh install, selected the drive, formatted the drive and proceed to new install. This time I couldn't boot on the DVD so I just launched the DVD install from Windows and selected "delete all files" (clean install).

My question is: is there a difference between these 2 methods? Considering that in my new install I can see my background image is still there for example, but other than that the C drive seems to have been emptied by Windows before install.

Comment: Difference is it does not (cannot) format the partition, just deletes all data from it.

Comment: Got it. But in terms of cleaning the system from malware, unnecessary software, fragmentation and anything making the system either slow or unsafe: in these respects is it better to format and if so how much better?

Comment: Formatting is up to you, I always do it when I perform a clean install but it is more of a habit than anything. Only way to format is when the OS is offline, by booting from the install media.

Answer (score 4):

There is a big difference between the two operations that you describe.

**Format followed by install**

This creates a really clean installation of Windows with nothing kept from
the previous installation and all user files are erased.
One must be careful to have available the installation media for all devices
for which Windows does not have a driver (or if the generic driver
is too limited).

With this mode one is assured that no corruption from the old version
will carry over into the new one.

**In-place upgrade**

There is not much official information about this process, so this answer
is pragmatic in nature and details can be changed without notice by Microsoft.

An in-place upgrade is started from inside the installed Windows installation
and uses it in order to refresh all Windows components to the new version.
This is not a totally clean installation.

The old installation that was used is saved in the renamed folder 
`Windows.old`. This is kept for 28 days, after which Windows will clean up
its files, leaving only user-created data such as the old desktop icons.

During the installation, one has to answer to the screen
"Choose what to keep" for what to keep from the old installation.

You have probably chosen the option of "Nothing".
The Nothing option relates more to `C:\Windows` than to your files,
so only Windows stuff like user accounts, registry and installed applications
are lost.
The installation may in this case allow the disk to be reformatted.

If the disk was not formatted, the old Windows installation in saved in
the `Windows.old` folder.
Some elements from the old installation will be transferred to the new one.
In your case it kept the old desktop image,
but it may also keep all drivers for all devices (unless the installation
media has newer versions).

If the installation of Windows was because of corruption in the old version,
with this mode there is always the possibility that it will carry over into
the new installation. If that happens, a clean installation is required.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting means removing all files but keeping the file system intact. Formatting means erasing the boot sector and the MFT (Master File Table) and replace it with a fresh one. Deleting is usually a more computationally expensive tasks, because every time a file is deleted, the MFT must be updated. Formatting is way faster since it just involve erasing the boot sector and the MFT (unless you do secure formatting, in which case it'll also write zeroes to the entire drive, ensuring that the data is not recoverable)

Comment: This is not quite correct. First, formatting does not affect the boot sector. And a full (not "quick") format is not secure. The data is still recoverable with the right tools... even after having "zeros" written to the filesystem. An actual secure disk wipe involves writing alternating streams of semi-random data to the hard drive to mask lingering magnetic signatures which might make data recoverable. Finally, all this applies to _just_ HDDs, not SSDs. SSDs should only ever be quick formatted and never secure wiped. A quick format is typically entirely secure for SSDs.

Comment: While this answer is mostly correct, it is not relevant to the question.